# What is the use case for a "Mixed" ASPX+ Portal page template?

Tags: kentico

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330216/difference-between-portal-template-and-aspx-template-in-kentico) regarding using portal engine vs. aspx, there is also the option for a "Mixed" template which the training defines as:

> This page template is based on an ASPX page located in the path specified in the File name field. ASPX+ Portal page templates are based on an ASPX page with additional page components that enable the Design tab.

What isn't clear is what the use case is for this mixed template.  When would you use this versus the other two?

**Update**

I read the following in the Developer Training materials:

> Sometimes, you may need to combine ASPX page templates or external ASPX pages with
>   Portal Engine page templates on a single web site. When developing or maintaining a
>   web site built on ASPX page templates, you must manually modify the code of a page
>   every time you want to change its design. But you can add flexibility to ASPX templates
>   by defining areas that can be edited directly through the browser using the CMS
>   administration interface (similar to the Portal Engine development model).

This explains clearly that it is a true hybrid where you have both ASPX template and Portal Engine functionality, but it isn't clear what benefit you have by using this approach versus a Portal Engine template that utilizes widgets or web parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say there is no "benefit" as such. You can use this mode e.g. when you are migrating existing ASPX web site to Kentico portal engine pages and replacing components (such as controls and web parts) one by one. When you finish the migration you can switch to portal engine mode. The goal was to provide this functionality for those who need it. It is recommended to use portal engine as you have complete control over the pages from CMS Desk.

Comment: That is helpful -- so really there wouldn't be a use case for it on brand new projects but where an existing solution built outside of Kentico is brought in to Kentico, this is a possible solution.  Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most common place I use them is when adding templates to a site using ASPX page templates, usually sites tend to have a content page, where I can swap out the controls (usually editable regions) with web part zones, then use that one template file to create multiple ASPX + Portal templates.

That way I can add a lot of new functionality into an existing site, without having to create half a dozen new .aspx templates.

I imagine it's also still useful for a new project where you want to keep your templates under source control, while utilizing the portal engine/web part functionality of Kentico.