# ASP.NET Pages Pages With CMS System

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, content-management-system

For the last two weeks I have been searching for a subject...
I'm an ASP.NET C# developer and I want to create a website that allows the use of CMS systems + .net pages,
I have seen some CMS like dotnetnuke, kentico, wordpress, MOTO, and so on...
Now, what is the best way to incorporate these two together... ASP.NET Pages (I create those) and some pages where I want the user to be able to use a CMS system to modify them.
Some people say I can use Wordpress site on one domain, then in the same hosting I create another to host my ASP.NET application... and use links to navigate to each others...
Is this the best way?
I'm completely confused on what to decide.

Comment: It depends what features you want, use the appropriate tools for the job, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kentico CMS you can benefit from wide range of [development models](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/portal_templates_vs_aspx_templates.htm). List of those you could be interested in follows:

1. Portal engine - pages are completely controlled by Kentico (design, content, properties, etc.)
2. ASPX - you develop ASPX pages in Visual Studio and use them in Kentico as they are. You can still edit their general properties (regarding urls, security, caching, etc).
3. [Mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305620/what-is-the-use-case-for-a-mixed-aspx-portal-page-template/16319110#16319110) - you create your pages in Visual Studio and use Kentico (server/user) controls which will allow you to edit design & content in Kentico UI.

Answer (score 0):

See Orchard CMS:

http://www.orchardproject.net/

Just assigning the right roles to users you get what you want. This CMS is writen in .Net and it license allows you to use it for any purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... :-) I will create the pages with Gridviews, Textboxes, and other asp.net controls.... but I need them to take the same site theme... some pages have very basic text that I want users to be able to edit... Hope I explained it better :-)